# Position fixed on top right relate to parent div

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

I have an html like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="vertical-btns">
    <button>Click</button>
    <button>Click</button>
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum erat rhoncus risus cursus tincidunt. Sed consequat eget tortor eget volutpat. Proin a hendrerit lacus. Vestibulum euismod sit amet velit id placerat. Nulla ipsum massa, ultricies at leo vitae, rhoncus dictum nisi. Fusce in pulvinar ante, ut dictum nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique sapien ante, vel dictum quam congue nec. Fusce molestie, velit at interdum malesuada, purus justo pharetra est, consectetur accumsan est lorem ac leo. Vestibulum at dolor metus. Nunc a quam ac velit dignissim vestibulum finibus sed sem. Maecenas aliquet dignissim risus, non congue justo fringilla mattis. Maecenas et scelerisque magna, eget vestibulum ipsum. Pellentesque tempor nunc felis, at tincidunt justo facilisis vel. Integer tincidunt, dolor at convallis venenatis, turpis nulla pretium erat, nec pellentesque ante justo vel risus
  </p>
  </br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum erat rhoncus risus cursus tincidunt. Sed consequat eget tortor eget volutpat. Proin a hendrerit lacus. Vestibulum euismod sit amet velit id placerat. Nulla ipsum massa, ultricies at leo vitae, rhoncus dictum nisi. Fusce in pulvinar ante, ut dictum nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique sapien ante, vel dictum quam congue nec. Fusce molestie, velit at interdum malesuada, purus justo pharetra est, consectetur accumsan est lorem ac leo. Vestibulum at dolor metus. Nunc a quam ac velit dignissim vestibulum finibus sed sem. Maecenas aliquet dignissim risus, non congue justo fringilla mattis. Maecenas et scelerisque magna, eget vestibulum ipsum. Pellentesque tempor nunc felis, at tincidunt justo facilisis vel. Integer tincidunt, dolor at convallis venenatis, turpis nulla pretium erat, nec pellentesque ante justo vel risus
  </p>
</br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum erat rhoncus risus cursus tincidunt. Sed consequat eget tortor eget volutpat. Proin a hendrerit lacus. Vestibulum euismod sit amet velit id placerat. Nulla ipsum massa, ultricies at leo vitae, rhoncus dictum nisi. Fusce in pulvinar ante, ut dictum nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique sapien ante, vel dictum quam congue nec. Fusce molestie, velit at interdum malesuada, purus justo pharetra est, consectetur accumsan est lorem ac leo. Vestibulum at dolor metus. Nunc a quam ac velit dignissim vestibulum finibus sed sem. Maecenas aliquet dignissim risus, non congue justo fringilla mattis. Maecenas et scelerisque magna, eget vestibulum ipsum. Pellentesque tempor nunc felis, at tincidunt justo facilisis vel. Integer tincidunt, dolor at convallis venenatis, turpis nulla pretium erat, nec pellentesque ante justo vel risus
  </p>
</br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum erat rhoncus risus cursus tincidunt. Sed consequat eget tortor eget volutpat. Proin a hendrerit lacus. Vestibulum euismod sit amet velit id placerat. Nulla ipsum massa, ultricies at leo vitae, rhoncus dictum nisi. Fusce in pulvinar ante, ut dictum nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique sapien ante, vel dictum quam congue nec. Fusce molestie, velit at interdum malesuada, purus justo pharetra est, consectetur accumsan est lorem ac leo. Vestibulum at dolor metus. Nunc a quam ac velit dignissim vestibulum finibus sed sem. Maecenas aliquet dignissim risus, non congue justo fringilla mattis. Maecenas et scelerisque magna, eget vestibulum ipsum. Pellentesque tempor nunc felis, at tincidunt justo facilisis vel. Integer tincidunt, dolor at convallis venenatis, turpis nulla pretium erat, nec pellentesque ante justo vel risus
  </p>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #71E764;
  max-width: 50rem;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
.vertical-btns {
  position: fixed;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
  flex: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  right: 0;
}
```

The result is that I have a container with 3 fixed buttons but outside of it. What I need is that the buttons stays inside the container on top right. But in this way, with right: 0, it's not relate to the parent container, but it seems relates to the web page. Is there a way to fix this?

that's the codepen and as you can see the buttos are totally on the right of the page instead of the container: https://codepen.io/eryonn/pen/oNBbOwe

Comment: you can just use ```.vertical-btns {float:right;}``` to fix at top right

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `right: 0;` for the element `.vertical-btns` use

```
margin-left: min(50rem, 100%);
transform: translateX(-100%);
```

---

**Why margin-left: min(50rem, 100%)?**

That's because your wrapper has not a fixed width, but just a `max-width`. So when the viewport is smaller than `50rem` it becomes responsive so also the `margin-left` must be lower, accordingly. More information about the CSS min() function can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min())

*Note 1*: if you're using a CSS preprocessor an error *could* be raised while compiling the source, probably because the preprocessor already has a `min()` function. If you want to use the CSS function instead change the case of the letters (e.g `Min(...)`) since the css function are case-insensitive

*Note 2*: if your browser doesn't support the min() function in this case you could use a mediaquery which will do the same thing (just a bit more verbose), e.g.

```
.vertical-btns { margin-left: 100% }

@media (min-width: 50rem) {
   .vertical-btns { margin-left: 50rem }
}
```

---

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. anyway, i have this error: ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Internal Error: Incompatible units: '%' and 'rem'.

Comment: Ok, well, there's another thing. In my application the container has a overflow-x and overflow-y. Both. So, your code is ok, but the buttons now are in the center of the parent container not on the right

Comment: I am sorry but I can just try to solve the code I see. You should have posted all the relevant code for the context from the beginning. change your demo with the other style.

Comment: Ok thanks, just a question, is it possible, here margin-left: min(50rem, 100%);, get the parent max-width instead write 50rem? because in my specific case could be variable

Comment: where is defined this variable? how do you set it to the max-width?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `position: absolute;` to position an element inside a parent with `position: relative;` and then `position: fixed;` on an element inside the absolute positioned

Answer (score 0):

"position: fixed" removes the element from the normal flow of the page and positions it in relation to the viewport. You can use "position: sticky" with "top:0" which will make your element stick to the top even when scrolling. Here's the code sample.

```
 .vertical-btns {
   position: sticky;
   padding-left: 20px;
   width: 100%;
   flex: auto;
   flex-direction: column;
   display: flex;
   align-items:flex-end;
   top:0;
   height:0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use `position: absoulte` instead of  `position: fixed`** and you can position your buttons relative to the container wherever you want ;-)

Position `fixed` is allways relative to viewport. Position àbsoute`is allways relative to the not`static`positioned parent element.

See example:

```css
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .container {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #71E764;
            max-width: 50rem;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            max-height: 500px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .vertical-btns {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            padding-left: 20px;
            width: inherit;

        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="vertical-btns">
    <button>Click</button>
    <button>Click</button>
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum erat rhoncus risus cursus tincidunt. Sed consequat eget tortor eget volutpat. Proin a hendrerit lacus. Vestibulum euismod sit amet velit id placerat. Nulla ipsum massa, ultricies at leo vitae, rhoncus dictum nisi. Fusce in pulvinar ante, ut dictum nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique sapien ante, vel dictum quam congue nec. Fusce molestie, velit at interdum malesuada, purus justo pharetra est, consectetur accumsan est lorem ac leo. Vestibulum at dolor metus. Nunc a quam ac velit dignissim vestibulum finibus sed sem. Maecenas aliquet dignissim risus, non congue justo fringilla mattis. Maecenas et scelerisque magna, eget vestibulum ipsum. Pellentesque tempor nunc felis, at tincidunt justo facilisis vel. Integer tincidunt, dolor at convallis venenatis, turpis nulla pretium erat, nec pellentesque ante justo vel risus
  </p>
  </br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum erat rhoncus risus cursus tincidunt. Sed consequat eget tortor eget volutpat. Proin a hendrerit lacus. Vestibulum euismod sit amet velit id placerat. Nulla ipsum massa, ultricies at leo vitae, rhoncus dictum nisi. Fusce in pulvinar ante, ut dictum nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique sapien ante, vel dictum quam congue nec. Fusce molestie, velit at interdum malesuada, purus justo pharetra est, consectetur accumsan est lorem ac leo. Vestibulum at dolor metus. Nunc a quam ac velit dignissim vestibulum finibus sed sem. Maecenas aliquet dignissim risus, non congue justo fringilla mattis. Maecenas et scelerisque magna, eget vestibulum ipsum. Pellentesque tempor nunc felis, at tincidunt justo facilisis vel. Integer tincidunt, dolor at convallis venenatis, turpis nulla pretium erat, nec pellentesque ante justo vel risus
  </p>
</br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum erat rhoncus risus cursus tincidunt. Sed consequat eget tortor eget volutpat. Proin a hendrerit lacus. Vestibulum euismod sit amet velit id placerat. Nulla ipsum massa, ultricies at leo vitae, rhoncus dictum nisi. Fusce in pulvinar ante, ut dictum nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique sapien ante, vel dictum quam congue nec. Fusce molestie, velit at interdum malesuada, purus justo pharetra est, consectetur accumsan est lorem ac leo. Vestibulum at dolor metus. Nunc a quam ac velit dignissim vestibulum finibus sed sem. Maecenas aliquet dignissim risus, non congue justo fringilla mattis. Maecenas et scelerisque magna, eget vestibulum ipsum. Pellentesque tempor nunc felis, at tincidunt justo facilisis vel. Integer tincidunt, dolor at convallis venenatis, turpis nulla pretium erat, nec pellentesque ante justo vel risus
  </p>
</br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus condimentum erat rhoncus risus cursus tincidunt. Sed consequat eget tortor eget volutpat. Proin a hendrerit lacus. Vestibulum euismod sit amet velit id placerat. Nulla ipsum massa, ultricies at leo vitae, rhoncus dictum nisi. Fusce in pulvinar ante, ut dictum nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque tristique sapien ante, vel dictum quam congue nec. Fusce molestie, velit at interdum malesuada, purus justo pharetra est, consectetur accumsan est lorem ac leo. Vestibulum at dolor metus. Nunc a quam ac velit dignissim vestibulum finibus sed sem. Maecenas aliquet dignissim risus, non congue justo fringilla mattis. Maecenas et scelerisque magna, eget vestibulum ipsum. Pellentesque tempor nunc felis, at tincidunt justo facilisis vel. Integer tincidunt, dolor at convallis venenatis, turpis nulla pretium erat, nec pellentesque ante justo vel risus
  </p>
</div>
```

---

*Note: Updated the code to comments.*

Comment: In this way the buttons are not floating

Comment: Well ... positioning the inner buttons is another question. Just remove flex stylings ... Buttons are inline element and show up side by side automatic.I updated the code for you.